# Selling Products by Linear Meter and Square Meter

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, dimensions, size-weight-units

**Question:** What is the best way to allow the user to purchase by linear meter?

**Context:** My company is putting together a basic Magento 2.2.2 store for a client (this is the first time we have worked with Magento). Our client needs to sell some products by linear meter and square meter. If I were building the site from the ground up, I'd be be putting in some kind of text box where the user could write a number, for example. This, however, is supposed to be a broadly "off the shelf" solution.

**What I know:** I have been doing some configuration with attribute sets and the like. However, nothing jumps out as immediately helpful.

**What I suspect:** You might tell me that the best way is to list each product as its own simple product and let the user select how many linear meters they want by changing the "Quantity" field of their order. It just doesn't feel very user friendly.

I hope that is clear and succinct.

Go easy on me, I'm new!

Mike